# file_get_contents and removing special characters

Tags: php, character, token

```html
<?php
$streamSite = "http://testsite.com/token.php";
function writeFile($url, $channel) {
$File = $channel.".strm";
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $url);
fclose($Handle);
}
$input = @file_get_contents($streamSite) or die("Please try again later: $url");
preg_match('/(m3u8.*hdnea=.*acl=.*~hmac=.*)/', $input, $matches);

echo $matches[1];


?>
```

;

Output but it does not work because of this **');** 
Can anyone help me out to remove the this **');** form the below outfile link . thank you 
 https://test.com/i/xxxx/master.m3u8hdnea=st=xxxxx~exp=xxxxxx~acl=/*~hmac=xxxxxx');